# Does the segue create an instance of the target ViewController? Should I remove them from the stack If I am done with them? If so, how?

Tags: swift

Please take a look at image I have shared. There are 4 ViewControllers in Main.storyboard:

[image: Main.storyboardview]

Here is the `viewController` list:

- AViewController
- BViewController
- CViewController
- DViewController

And AViewController is an initial ViewController.

- AViewController has one button which is named 'Take Me To The
  BViewController'
- BViewController has two buttons:  'Take Me To The CViewController'
  and Back Button
- CViewController has two buttons:  'Take Me To The CViewController'
  and Back Button
- DViewController has two buttons:  'Take Me To The AViewController'
  and Back Button

There are also 4 segues as you see:

- First segue is A to B
- Second segue is B to C
- Third segue is C to D
- Fourth segue is D to A

I wrote below code for these buttons:

```
self.performSegue(withIdentifier: "takeMeToTheBViewController", sender : self)
self.performSegue(withIdentifier: "takeMeToTheCViewController", sender : self)
self.performSegue(withIdentifier: "takeMeToTheDViewController", sender : self)
self.performSegue(withIdentifier: "takeMeToTheAViewController", sender : self)
```

And I wrote below code for the back button action:

```
self.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
```

I have 3 questions:

**First scenario:** Let's assume I open the app. And then I click button in `AViewController`. This action takes me to the BViewController. And then I click `takeMeToTheCViewController` button in `BViewController`. This action takes me to the `CViewController`. And then I click `takeMeToTheDViewController` button in `CViewController`. This action takes me to the `DViewController`. And then I click `takeMeToTheAViewController` button in `DViewController`. This action takes me to the `AViewController`. 
**Here is the question 1:** 
Can you tell me instances in stack after all these actions? Are below items true for the stack?

- instance of `AViewController(1)`,
- instance of `AViewController(2)`,
- instance of `BViewController`,
- instance of `CViewController`,
- instance of `DViewController`

**Here is the question 1.1:**
Please reply this question according to first scenario above. 
If above instances items are true what should I do to remove below instances from the stack:

- instance of `AViewController(2)`,
- instance of `BViewController`,
- instance of `CViewController`,
- instance of `DViewController`

Because I don't need them now. I only need AViewController(1) because i am in AViewController currently.

**Second scenario:** Let's continue on first scenario. I was in first page. Now I click 'takeMeToTheBViewController' button in AViewController.
**Here is the question 2:** 
Can you tell me instances in stack after all these actions? Are below items true for the stack?

- instance of `AViewController(1)`,
- instance of `AViewController(2)`,
- instance of `BViewController(1)`,
- instance of `BViewController(2)`,
- instance of `CViewController`,
- instance of `DViewController`

**Third scenario:** Let's continue on second scenario. I was in second page. Now I click 'back' button in BViewController(with dissmiss code as you know) This action takes me to the AViewController. 
**Here is the question 3:** 
Can you tell me instances in stack after all these actions? Are below items true for the stack?

- instance of `AViewController(1)`,
- instance of `AViewController(2)`,
- instance of `BViewController(1)`,
- instance of `CViewController`,
- instance of `DViewController`

I mean instance of `BViewController(2)` is removed from the stack by clicking `back` button. Is this true?

**Here is the question 4:**
Would it be a crash problem if these instances accumulate in the stack?
Can you reply with question numbers please?

Comment: You might want to consider using a "unwind" operation.  Essentially, you create a `@IBAction` at the point to "unwind" (ie `AViewController(1)`), then you setup a segue from the which ever controllers you need to it via the storyboard

Comment: @MadProgrammer Is it possible to answer with question numbers so that I can better understand?

Comment: 1. Yes  1.1 Use an unwind segue to go from D back to A  2 Yes. 3 Yes. 4. Yes, you’ll run out of memory and your app will quit.

Comment: @vacawama Can we print which items are in the stack? (Items means: like an instance of the AViewController, instance of the BViewController etc) Can we print them with print method to see result in output window? If reply is yes, How can I write items in the stack with print method?

Comment: If your viewControllers are in a `UINavigationController`, then inside of any viewController, you can `print(self.navigationController!.viewControllers)`.  That array is the list of viewControllers on the stack controlled by the `navigationController`.

Comment: Thanks. What if my viewControllers are not in a UINavigationController? Should I write print code in AppDelegate.swift in didFinishLaunchingWithOptions method? If yes, Can you also say this please? @vacawama

Comment: You can start with the current VC and ask it for `self.presentingViewController`.  You can then ask that one for its `.presentingViewController`, and so on.  See [the documentation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiviewcontroller/1621430-presentingviewcontroller)